# How to use IN with string comma separated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have value in table1 like this:

```
Value
-------
JT, KF, LF
```

On select in other table how can I get a value like this

```
Select a.Field from table2
Inner Join Table1 on Table1.field = Table2.field
Where Type IN(Table2.Value)
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

Which version of SQL are you using?  If you are in 2016+ then you can use `STRING_SPLIT` (see example below).

```
SELECT a.Field 
FROM table2
    INNER JOIN Table1 
        ON Table1.field = Table2.field
WHERE Type IN 
    ( 
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(P.[value])) 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(Table1.[Value], ',') AS P
    )
```

<sub>***Reference:** [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sub>

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, this is correct. Upvoting to restore order to the universe.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Fite has a good functional answer based on the criteria of the original question.

However, I feel we'd being doing an injustice if no one called out that STRING_SPLIT is going to run on every row in Table1. Depending on how big Tabel1 is or will become in the future, that could be a lot of overhead. Depending on how established the tables is, it might make better sense to split these values before they're inserted into the database.